# Eliminar varios caracteres de una url con la función str_replace() de PHP

Tags: php, url

Tengo una función de PHP para eliminar caracteres en la url que la función `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` no me logra limpiar pero para lograrlo tengo tengo que quitar una línea de código porque ya esta colocado un str_replace y lo que quiero saber es si puedo colocar mas de str_replace y como podría hacerlo.

### Función para limpiar mi url

```
// Limpiar url
function clearUrl($title){
    // Pasar la variable titulo por la URL
    $titleURL = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
    $titleURL = str_replace('?', '', $titleURL);
    $titleURL = strtolower($titleURL); 
    $titleURL = filter_var($titleURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    return $titleURL; 
}
```

Lo que sucede es que al colocar esta línea de código `$titleURL = str_replace('?', '', $title);` dentro de la función me ignora la primera y necesito ambas porque quiero eliminar este **"?"** signo de mis url pero busco una forma de que con un mismo str_replace() lograr reemplazar espacios por "-" guiones y "?" signos de cerrar interrogación por "" nada

Espero que hayan entendido lo que quiero lograr y me brinden una forma para lograrlo, un saludo.

Comment: Saludos. Prueba con https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Al agregar la línea que reemplaza el signo `?` por nada, ¿has tenido la precaución de cambiar la variable que recibe la siguiente línea por `$titleURL`?

Comment: @Marcos Sabes que tienes razón, yo le pasaba la variable `$title` cuando debería de pasarle la variable `$titleURL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema en tu función y es que en la línea de código donde intentas remplazar "?" por nada estas colocando la variable `$title` cuando deberías de colocar la variable `$titleURL` para que el código te pueda funcionar bien. Porque actualmente como esta tu código lo que hace es que ignora la línea de código de arriba cuando toca leer la de abajo logrando que se pierdan los cambios de remplazar los espacios por "-" guiones.

### Código con la función ya resuelta

```
// Limpiar url
function clearUrl($title){
    // Pasar la variable titulo por la URL
    $titleURL = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
    $titleURL = str_replace('?', '', $titleURL);
    $titleURL = strtolower($titleURL); 
    $titleURL = filter_var($titleURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    return $titleURL; 
}
```